# How to upload sensor data on pubnub IOT with JSON Format?

Tags: wifi, nodemcu, json, iot

I am trying to send MPU9250 sensor data to Pubnub IOT platform using node mcu, but not able to do it since the sensor data is not in JSON format. I know about publishing string but don't know about variable.

About Pubnub Library - https://github.com/pubnub/arduino

This is the part which I need help in:-

```
IMU.readSensor();

PubNonSubClient *pclient = PubNub.publish(pubchannel, IMU.getAccelX_mss());
```

But above line has error so how do i send imu sensor data to pubnub? All connections are right and sensor is working since I tested it.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the debug option? To enable debug logging to the Arduino console, add `#define PUBNUB_DEBUG` before `#include <PubNub.h>`

Comment: format it in json before sending it out, for small payloads, hand-building JSON isn't that hard.

Answer (score 1):

This is the format which helped me to upload the data successfully. I didn't knew what JSON format was and got stuck. In case if someone stumbles on a similar problem.

```
char buf[5] = {};

sprintf(buf, "\"%d\"", IMU.getAccelX_mss());

PubNonSubClient *pclient = PubNub.publish(pubchannel, buf);
```